# socket.io-client can't get authorization fail reason

Tags: node.js, socket.io

- socket.io@0.9.9
- socket.io-client@0.9.9
- express@3.0.0rc1

**server code:**

```
//run with node-dev server.js
var remoteServer = io.of('/remote');
remoteServer.authorization(function(handshakeData, callback){
  return callback('unknown clientType', false);
}
```

**the server log:**

```
You can visit your app with http://localhost:3000
   info  - handshake authorized l4FzYiWpHo2d8VeoB3Zo
   warn  - handshake error unknown clientType for /remote
```

**client code:**

```
//run with node-dev client.js
var io = require('socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client');
var client = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/remote');
client.on('connect_failed', function(reason){
  console.log('connect_failed:', reason);
});

//will call this because it's Namespace authorization
client.on('error', function(reason){
  console.log('error:', reason);
});
```

**the client log:**

```
//error reason miss.
E:\Workspace\TZ\SmartDoor\client>node-dev client.js
error:
```

Comment: after read the src and test, found that authorization don't allow custom error msg, only callback(null,false) then client got: "error: unauthorized"

Comment: now, I should delete this question or close? which op

Comment: so how could I tell the client more detail of authorization fail msg?

Comment: From the socket.io docs, it sounds like there is no option to add a reason why the authorization was denied. All your allowed to say is true/false for the authorization.

Comment: @atian25 Add your solution as an answer. Do not close it, as it contains valuable information.

Comment: @KurtPattyn I didn't found the solution, `socket.io@0.9.9` don't support that feature. And I don't know whether it's supported now.

Answer (score 1):

`authorization` in Socket.IO is **middleware** to handle Handshake process based on HTTP Header data that is sent with first HTTP Switch Protocols header in case of WebSockets.

This data contains normal header stuff as well as cookies and is used to restore session sometimes.
Although `authorization` middleware happens before actual WebSockets handshake process has been accomplished, and this middleware should not be used for application logic authorization, but only for networking and http stuff (like cookies for restoring session, banned IP, etc).

So I will recommend of not using this middleware for application logic as it is actually protocol specific as well (Socket.IO uses many protocols and communication layers like WebSockets, XHR Long Polling, AJAX, etc). But do your authentication logic after connection is successfully established.